# Wsimport failing when building with JDK 21

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I am trying to upgrade a service from Java 8 to JDK 17. I am pretty new to Maven. Below is the maven pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>${testversion}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Test Project</name>
    <url></url>

        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.7</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
              <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>${wsdlDir}</wsdlDirectory>
                <bindingDirectory></bindingDirectory>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDestDir>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <xjcArgs>
                  <xjcArg>-Xsetters</xjcArg>
                </xjcArgs>
              </configuration>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                  <version>2.0.9</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            
            
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

When  try to build this using Maven, I am getting an error while parsing the wsdl files.

```
parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] Unexpected <bindings> appears at line 5 column 17
  line 5 of http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:74)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.AbortException
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:114)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2265)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:164)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:111)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:413)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:180)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:158)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        ... 2 more
```

Below is the jax-ws binding file being used(removed some details due to policies)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings version="2.1" wsdlLocation=""
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl">
    
    <globalBindings>
        <javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
                  parseMethod=""
                  printMethod=""
        />
        <javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                  parseMethod=""
                  printMethod=""
        />
        <xjc:serializable/>
    </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

The same configuration worked when building the project using Java 8. Can someone let me know what the issue is here exactly? I am pretty new to these plugins so having a hard time finding the issue.

**Edit:**

wsimport is working now using the suggestion by Laurent

Facing build issues for one of the xml-beans generation POM. Building with Openjdk 21. Below is the POM.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-xmlbeans</artifactId>
<version>${testversion}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Test XMLBeans Generation Project</name>
<url></url>

<build>
<resources>
       <resource>
            <directory>${wsdlDir}</directory>
            <targetPath>xsd</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${wsdlDir}</schemaDirectory>

                <noUpa>true</noUpa>
                <noVDoc>true</noVDoc>
                <memoryInitialSize>64m</memoryInitialSize>
                <memoryMaximumSize>512m</memoryMaximumSize>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Below is the error I am getting during the build

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.xmlbeans.XmlBeansException:XmlBeans compile failed:    
xml ErrorLoading wsdl file test.wsdl
xml ErrorProcessing 1 schema(s) in test.wsdl
```

Comment: XMLBeans maven plugin is documented at https://xmlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html - it has changed a little bit since v2.4 - latest is v5.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer

From what I understand, you're trying to migrate only from JDK8 to JDK21 based on your comments. You should then stick to javax-based packages (if no other upgrades planned)

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsimport</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <wsdlDirectory>${wsdlDir}</wsdlDirectory>
    <bindingDirectory></bindingDirectory>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <!-- you should generate sources in a target subdirectory -->
    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDestDir>
    <extension>true</extension>
    <xjcArgs>
      <!-- based on usage of jaxb2-basics -->
      <xjcArg>-Xsetters</xjcArg>
    </xjcArgs>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <!-- move from org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons:collection-setter-injector to jaxb2-basics -->
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

### XMLBeans answer

Since the plugin is quite outdated (last release in 2009), I'd suggest to move to the maven-plugin equivalent of [JAXB-Tools](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools)

Here is a sample configuration which is equivalent to your's from my understanding :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${wsdlDir}</schemaDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'd also suggest you to add the dependency of jaxb-ri in your dependencies since it's no more provided by the JDK since JDK9.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

### Initial answer

Three points for the above configuration :

**1. Your header definition is incorrect for jakarta migration**

It should be the following

```xml
<bindings version="3.0" wsdlLocation=""
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl">
```

If you're not targeting jakarta (for example, having Spring below v6 / SpringBoot below v3) but want only Java17, then the plugin itself should be changed to the following :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <!-- configuration like above here -->
</plugin>
```

**2. I've seen a wrong dependency in your plugin**

In general, provide only needed dependencies on your plugin. Overriding could lead to error in config.

The following should be removed or replace by it's jakarta equivalent :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-MR1</version>
</dependency>
```

Jakarta's coordinates :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**3. I've also seen you're using the following plugin which is not under active dev :**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This plugin is in `org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.0` you can find [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) and can be activated with `-Xsetters` (documentation of the plugin [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Setters-Plugin). Just replace the above dependency with the new one.

For jakarta-based version, use this :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-plugins</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For non-jakarta-based version, use this :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Another point : some plugins in `org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons` groupId are currently integrated in 4.0.1 of jaxb-plugins.

Comment: Hey Laurent, Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the header definition as you pointed put and I'm still getting the same error. There is a Warning message in the terminal while building which says "[WARNING] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
  line 5 of http://dummy.pseudo-schema#schema2". Can you guide me on how to overcome this?

Comment: Could you tell me if you're targeting javax or jakarta based packages ? Depending of your answer, that'd change my answer.

Comment: Also do you have any bindings in your wsdl / xsd ? If targeting jakarta, you should upgrade namespace there too (for bindings and wsdl)

Comment: I am trying to build using Openjdk 21. Not sure on what packages I should target. I am trying to migrate this service from idk 8 to 21. And yes, my wsdl files have bindings. Can you please let me know how to build successfully?

Comment: If you only plan a jdk upgrade without going to jakarta, you should stick to javax-based version of the plugin (will update my answer this way to tell which config should work)

Comment: Answer updated, please also rollback changes to your binding files

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! I am getting a new error with this configuration saying that "package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist". May be I have to include those dependencies as well?

Comment: If the generation is correct, I'd suggest you add the following dependency to your project (and not to your plugin) `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.7`. You should get all needed classes by transitivity :)

Comment: Added the dependency, but still getting the same error.
error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class XmlAccessorType
error: package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist

Comment: Could you share more of the pom ?

Comment: Edited the post with the complete pom.

Comment: You have only set the jaxws-rt in dependenciesManagment section, you still need to add it in dependencies section (without version tag if previous kept)

Comment: Thanks! I added it and it worked! Also, I have another child pom which is for xml-beans generation. When I try to build it with jdk 21, getting an error saying it is not able to load the schema file(xsd). Can you suggest on how I could make it work with jdk 21? I am editing the post with the xml-beans pom.

Comment: It'd be nice to have access to chat mode but didn't know how to trigger it...
Since you only want JDK21 support and since I have no idea what the `xmlbeans-maven-plugin` is doing (last release = 2009), I'd suggest trying to use the maven-plugin from jaxb-tools. Editing the answer to provide example

Comment: Have you tried the Apache XMLBeans plugin? Codehaus plugin is ancient. mlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html